# Getting a Double value from an EditText

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

I want to input a numeric value into an EditText box. The InputType is specified as "numberDecimal|numberSigned". The code I've found that works is:

`mLatitude = txtLatitude.text.toString().toDouble()`

This seems unnecessarily convoluted. Can it really be necessary to convert first to a string then to a double? Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double.parseDouble() would not accept Editable that is returned by txtLatitude.text.

You can create your own extension if you want

```
fun Editable.toDouble() = toString().toDouble()

fun test() {
    mLatitude = txtLatitude.text.toDouble()
}
```

Comment: I voted you up because you were the first person to post and it's your right to be the accepted answer. a try-catch block would make sense also

Answer (score 2):

There is no another way. For convenience you can create an extension function on `EditText`:

```
fun EditText.getDouble(): Double = try {
    text.toString().toDouble()
} catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    0.0
}
```

And use it like this:

```
val latitude = editText.getDouble()
```